# UIGestureRecognizer on UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIImageView`, which I want to be able to resize and rotate etc.

Can a `UIGestureRecognizer` be added to the `UIImageView`?

I would want to add a rotate and pinch recognizer to a `UIImageView` which would be created at runtime.

How does one add these recognizers?

Comment: UIImageView's super class is UIView so you can add gestureRecognizer to your UIImageView

Answer (score 434, accepted):

Check that `userInteractionEnabled` is `YES` on the `UIImageView`.  Then you can add a gesture recognizer.

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pgr = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] 
    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
pgr.delegate = self;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:pgr];
[pgr release];
:
:
- (void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchGestureRecognizer
{
  //handle pinch...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will this not resize the image as pinching does, or how would this be handled to resize the image as the pinch gesture is recognized?

Comment: No, this just shows how to add the gesture recognizers.  You have to do the actual zoom/rotate yourself in the gesture handlers.  See the sample app [Touches_GestureRecognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007435) on how to do the zoom/rotate.

Comment: +1 sat here for ages trying to figure out why my gestures wouldn't work..  "Check that userInteractionEnabled is YES on the UIImageView." Thanks!

Comment: This definitely made my work easier than trying to set limits on a recognizer set to the overall view.  Thanks!

Comment: imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
this is the key! Thank you.

Comment: @Anna can you translate this code in swift also please?

Comment: `userInteractionEnabled` still must be set to YES/true in Xcode 8 Objective-C/Swift

Answer (score 78):

Yes, a UIGestureRecognizer can be added to a UIImageView. As stated in the other answer, it is very important to remember to enable user interaction on the image view by setting its `userInteractionEnabled` property to `YES`. UIImageView inherits from UIView, whose user interaction property is set to `YES` by default, however, UIImageView's user interaction property is set to `NO` by default.

From the [UIImageView docs:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> New image view objects are configured to disregard user events by
>   default. If you want to handle events in a custom subclass of
>   UIImageView, you must explicitly change the value of the
>   userInteractionEnabled property to YES after initializing the object.

Anyway, on the the bulk of the answer. Here's an example of how to create a `UIImageView` with a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`, a `UIRotationGestureRecognizer`, and a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

First, in `viewDidLoad`, or another method of your choice, create an image view, give it an image, a frame, and enable its user interaction. Then create the three gestures as follows. Be sure to utilize their delegate property (most likely set to self). This will be required to use multiple gestures at the same time.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // set up the image view
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage"]];
    [imageView setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 120.0, 120.0)];
    [imageView setCenter:self.view.center];
    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; // <--- This is very important

    // create and configure the pinch gesture
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGestureRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinchGestureDetected:)];
    [pinchGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGestureRecognizer];

    // create and configure the rotation gesture
    UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationGestureRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotationGestureDetected:)];
    [rotationGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:rotationGestureRecognizer];

    // creat and configure the pan gesture
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGestureDetected:)];
    [panGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];


    [self.view addSubview:imageView]; // add the image view as a subview of the view controllers view
}
```

Here are the three methods that will be called when the gestures on your view are detected. Inside them, we will check the current state of the gesture, and if it is in either the began or changed `UIGestureRecognizerState` we will read the gesture's scale/rotation/translation property, apply that data to an affine transform, apply the affine transform to the image view, and then reset the gestures scale/rotation/translation.

```
- (void)pinchGestureDetected:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    UIGestureRecognizerState state = [recognizer state];

    if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGFloat scale = [recognizer scale];
        [recognizer.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, scale, scale)];
        [recognizer setScale:1.0];
    }
}

- (void)rotationGestureDetected:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    UIGestureRecognizerState state = [recognizer state];

    if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGFloat rotation = [recognizer rotation];
        [recognizer.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate(recognizer.view.transform, rotation)];
        [recognizer setRotation:0];
    }
}

- (void)panGestureDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    UIGestureRecognizerState state = [recognizer state];

    if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:recognizer.view];
        [recognizer.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformTranslate(recognizer.view.transform, translation.x, translation.y)];
        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:recognizer.view];
    }
}
```

Finally and very importantly, you'll need to utilize the [UIGestureRecognizerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) method `gestureRecognizer: shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` to allow the gestures to work at the same time. If these three gestures are the only three gestures that have this class assigned as their delegate, then you can simply return `YES` as shown below. However, if you have additional gestures that have this class assigned as their delegate, you may need to add logic to this method to determine which gesture is which before allowing them to all work together.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Don't forget to make sure that your class conforms to the [UIGestureRecognizerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol. To do so, make sure that your interface looks something like this:

```
@interface MyClass : MySuperClass <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

If you prefer to play with the code in a working sample project yourself, the sample project I've created containing this code [can be found here.](https://github.com/NSPostWhenIdle/GestureImageView)

Comment: This is by far the best answer I have ever seen in stackoverflow.com, full detailed, well commented and even includes source code on git. Thanks for that

Comment: Clear, step by step, awesome explaination

Comment: Thank you, that did in a page or two what several dozen tutorials over years by Apple and others failed to do.  I feel that there must be many other things in iOS that are possible, but due to obfuscation and misunderstanding they are lost to us.

Comment: Great answer, the best one. Thanks a lot for your patience.

Answer (score 15):

### Swift 4.2

```
myImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped))
tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
myImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

and when tapped:

```
@objc func imageTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
   // do something when image tapped
   print("image tapped")
}
```

Answer (score 11):

### Swift 2.0 Solution

You create a tap, pinch or swipe gesture recognizer in the same manor. Below I'll walk you through 4 steps to getting your recognizer up and running.

**4 Steps**

**1.)** Inherit from `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` by adding it to your class signature.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {...}
```

**2.)** Control drag from your image to your viewController to create an IBOutlet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tapView: UIImageView!
```

**3.)** In your viewDidLoad add the following code:

```
// create an instance of UITapGestureRecognizer and tell it to run 
// an action we'll call "handleTap:"
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
// we use our delegate
tap.delegate = self
// allow for user interaction
tapView.userInteractionEnabled = true
// add tap as a gestureRecognizer to tapView
tapView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

**4.)** Create the function that will be called when your gesture recognizer is tapped. (You can exclude the `= nil` if you choose).

```
func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    // just creating an alert to prove our tap worked!
    let tapAlert = UIAlertController(title: "hmmm...", message: "this actually worked?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    tapAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Destructive, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(tapAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

---

Your final code should look something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tapView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
        tap.delegate = self
        tapView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        tapView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
        let tapAlert = UIAlertController(title: "hmmm...", message: "this actually worked?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        tapAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Destructive, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(tapAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: i wrote a blog about this here: http://www.codebeaulieu.com/3/UIGestureRecognier-programatically

Answer (score 5):

I just done this with swift4 by adding 3 gestures together in single view

1. **UIPinchGestureRecognizer** : Zoom in and zoom out view.
2. **UIRotationGestureRecognizer** : Rotate the view.
3. **UIPanGestureRecognizer** : Dragging the view.

Here my sample code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{
      //your image view that outlet from storyboard or xibs file.
     @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!
     // declare gesture recognizer
     var panRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer?
     var pinchRecognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer?
     var rotateRecognizer: UIRotationGestureRecognizer?

     override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          // Create gesture with target self(viewcontroller) and handler function.  
          self.panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handlePan(recognizer:)))
          self.pinchRecognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handlePinch(recognizer:)))
          self.rotateRecognizer = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleRotate(recognizer:)))
          //delegate gesture with UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
          pinchRecognizer?.delegate = self
          rotateRecognizer?.delegate = self
          panRecognizer?.delegate = self
          // than add gesture to imgView
          self.imgView.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer!)
          self.imgView.addGestureRecognizer(pinchRecognizer!)
          self.imgView.addGestureRecognizer(rotateRecognizer!)
     }

     // handle UIPanGestureRecognizer 
     @objc func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {    
          let gview = recognizer.view
          if recognizer.state == .began || recognizer.state == .changed {
               let translation = recognizer.translation(in: gview?.superview)
               gview?.center = CGPoint(x: (gview?.center.x)! + translation.x, y: (gview?.center.y)! + translation.y)
               recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: gview?.superview)
          }
     }

     // handle UIPinchGestureRecognizer 
     @objc func handlePinch(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
          if recognizer.state == .began || recognizer.state == .changed {
               recognizer.view?.transform = (recognizer.view?.transform.scaledBy(x: recognizer.scale, y: recognizer.scale))!
               recognizer.scale = 1.0
         }
     }   

     // handle UIRotationGestureRecognizer 
     @objc func handleRotate(recognizer: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
          if recognizer.state == .began || recognizer.state == .changed {
               recognizer.view?.transform = (recognizer.view?.transform.rotated(by: recognizer.rotation))!
               recognizer.rotation = 0.0
           }
     }

     // mark sure you override this function to make gestures work together 
     func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
         return true
     }

}
```

Any question, just type to comment. thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can also drag a tap gesture recogniser to the image view in `Storyboard`. Then create an action by `ctrl + drag` to the code.

Answer (score 2):

**SWIFT 3 Example**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.backgroundImageView.addGestureRecognizer(
        UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action:#selector(didTapImageview(_:)))
    )

    self.backgroundImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

func didTapImageview(_ sender: Any) {
    // do something
}
```

No gesture recongnizer delegates or other implementations where necessary.

Answer (score 1):

For Blocks lover you can use [ALActionBlocks](https://github.com/lavoy/ALActionBlocks) to add action of gestures in block

```
__weak ALViewController *wSelf = self;
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithBlock:^(UITapGestureRecognizer *weakGR) {
    NSLog(@"pan %@", NSStringFromCGPoint([weakGR locationInView:wSelf.view]));
}];
[self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:gr];
```