# Adding Tap Gesture on UIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, core-animation

I am trying to make clickable UIImage, where the user can click it then it'll animate...

i am working with the UIScrollVIew that's why i used the UITapGesture instead of touchesBegan, and it seems that UIGestureRecognizer is not compatible with UIImage...

am i right?

i keep receiving this error message

> receiver type 'UIImage' for instance message does not declare a method
>   with selector 'addGestureRecognizer'

is there any other way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GestureRecognizer on UIImageView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907397/gesturerecognizer-on-uiimageview)

Answer (score 28):

You have to add TapGesture in UIImageView not UIImage

```
imgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(tapGesture:)];

tapGesture1.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

[tapGesture1 setDelegate:self];

[imgView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture1];

[tapGesture1 release];
```

You can response to the tap with the defined selector and do stuff there

```
- (void) tapGesture: (id)sender
{
    //handle Tap...
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to add the gesture to UIImageView, not UIImage

Comment: it's not working with Core Animation. what i'm trying to do here is that, the image will animate when you click it.

Comment: The point here is that UIImage cannot receive touch event. You have to handle the touch event somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add a TapGestureRecognizer to a UIImageView. You have to use a UIImageView because gesture recognizer are only allowed to be added to views.

```
UIView *someView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)];
tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[someView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

You can response to the tap with the defined selector and do stuff there

```
- (void)tapAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `UIButton` instead of `UIIMage` and make the `UIButton` type **custom**. And on clicking the same you can show the animation.

Comment: can UIButton be animated? i used the UIImage because of CoreAnimation.

Comment: Thats only a workaround but not the right answer. The Best way is to add the gesture to UIImageView. Don't abuse buttons as Images that's not the right way to do it.

Comment: @mariusLAN : you can share your idea as an answer.

Comment: @mariusLAN : I'd also suggest that you justify your answer.  There are many ways to solve any problem, but UIButtons are designed to trigger events when the user touches a location screen.  That's what the Crisn is asking for.