# Programmatically create UIButtons on CircleImage

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, geometry, obshapedbutton

I need to create Arch shaped `UIButtons`, on a circle image.(the O/p need to look like Concentric Circles),

At present I am using 5 images, but in future I may add some more Images, Dynamically I need to fil the circle Image with the added images.

I had a sample Piece of code and  O/P is the below image

```
int numberOfSections = 6;
    CGFloat angleSize = 2*M_PI/numberOfSections;
 for (int j = 0; j < numberOfSections; ++j) {
        UIButton *sectionLabel = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 150.0f, 2.0f)];
sectionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
 sectionLabel.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0f, 0.5f);
        sectionLabel.layer.position = CGPointMake(container.bounds.size.width/2.0, container.bounds.size.height/2.0); // places anchorPoint of each label directly in the center of the circle.
        sectionLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleSize*j);
        [container addSubview:sectionLabel];
    }
```

[image: Image for Above Code]

I have tried with this piece of code and the O/P is the below image

```
 int numberOfSections = 5;
    CGFloat angleSize = 2*M_PI/numberOfSections;
    for (int j = 0; j<numberOfSections; ++j) {
        UIImage *imageframe = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:j];
OBShapedButton *button = [[OBShapedButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 150.0f, 150.0f, 128.0f)];
button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleSize*j);
[container addSubview:button];
}
```

[image: 2nd Image]

I need my output as the below image 
[image: 3rd Image]

How can i Achieve that

O/P after I Tried with  Sarah Zuo's code

[image: Sarah Zuo Code]

same width and height  buttons [image: Sarah Zuo code 2nd answer]
AnyKind of Help is more Appreciated

Comment: will the new images get added in the same circle reducing the current arc of the existing imageviews??

Comment: @AppleDelegate : Yes, we will be giving the images count so that it makes the division

Answer (score 4):

I can answer only last part,

If you are able to get images for buttons, then you can refer [this tutorial](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2010/03/irregularly-shaped-uibuttons.html). This might help you. Provided, your image formed is having transparent background.

Comment: @CrazyCreator : I am just placing the images for the button background , but how can i get the buttons in circle type.

Comment: U can never create a circular shaped button, this is the hack you need. keep other parts transparent, and ur button will look like circular.

Answer (score 2):

```
float radius = container.bounds.size.width / 2;
int numberOfSections = 5;
CGFloat angleSize = 2*M_PI/numberOfSections;
for (int j = 0; j<numberOfSections; ++j) {
    UIImage *imageframe = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:j];
    OBShapedButton *button = [[OBShapedButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 150.0f, 150.0f, 128.0f)];

    button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(2*M_PI-angleSize*j);
    button.center = CGPointMake(radius + radius * sin(angleSize * j) / 2, radius +  radius * cos(angleSize * j) / 2);
    [container addSubview:button];
}
```

Try this code.

Comment: Now when i tried with ur code , i got inside part as pentagon

Comment: when i am trying with this piece of code, i am getting the inner part as the pentagon, where the buttons are coming to outer part of the circle

Comment: I have updated my answer Can u please check the last screenshot in the Question

Comment: It seems I used wrong value for button.center and button.transform. I fixed the center value, but slices of button is confused.

Comment: yeah i hope, can u check that once if possible, i am trying that with different values, i am not getting the right output could u check that

Answer (score 1):

You can use your `UIImageView` instead. You can give different `tag` to image view and add [Gesture Recognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907397/gesturerecognizer-on-uiimageview). Now you can get touch events like button click event on image views.

Comment: The Circle Image is one UIImageView,

Answer (score 1):

If all buttons' image look like the one (same direction), the transform value may be work.

```
button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(2*M_PI-angleSize*j);
button.center = CGPointMake(radius + radius * sin(angleSize * j) / 2, radius +  radius * cos(angleSize * j) / 2);
```

[image: button slice]

Comment: though the buttons have the same widtha dn height i am getting same type, i shall i add that image too, please check the image lastly added in 2 mins

Comment: @Srinivas , anything going to be better?